# Is there a tool to shrink/grow raster data edge by n pixels

Tags: raster, gdal, software-recommendations, postgis-raster

Looking for an open source tool to grow/shrink raster edge by n pixels. I noticed Grass has r.grow but hoping there might be a way to do it with GDAL, PostGIS or python library.

More information:
I want to shrink it around the edge where I have data not the entire rectangular region.
Consider this raster: 
[image]

Comment: Check the extents and pixel size of the original image with gdalinfo, calculate the desired xmin ymin xmax ymax values feed them to -te (target extents) parameter of gdalwarp http://www.gdal.org/gdalwarp.html. For making all that automatically you should write a script.

Comment: Thanks but I think that will warp all the data, I just want to remove pixels along the edge where data exists. I've added an example.

Comment: If input srs and output srs are the same the pixels are just copied. But our image clarifies your question and adjusting the extents does not help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up making a GRASS script to mitigate edge effect from course imagery such as Landsat 8. Script is as follows. I know each step could be simplified but have it in steps helps understand what is going on.

Basically it does a neighbourhood count. It uses the output to discover the  edge of the imagery. These gaps are given a null value. The null value is filled in with median value from 5x5 neighbourhood. The output is then masked to the original image.

See input & output side by side.

[image: Input]

[image: Output]

```
run_command("r.neighbors",
            overwrite = True,
            input = "in@PERMANENT",
            output = "count",
            method = "count",
            size = 5)

run_command("r.mapcalc",
            overwrite = True,
            expression = "step1=if(count@PERMANENT<25  &  count@PERMANENT>0,0,1)")

run_command("r.mapcalc",
            overwrite = True,
            expression = "step2=if( step1@PERMANENT==0,null(),1)")

run_command("r.mapcalc",
            overwrite = True,
            expression = "step3=if( count@PERMANENT ==0,0,1)* step2@PERMANENT")

run_command("r.mapcalc",
            overwrite = True,
            expression = "step4=if(isnull(in@PERMANENT )==1,0,in@PERMANENT)")

run_command("r.mapcalc",
            overwrite = True,
            expression = "step5=step4@PERMANENT * step3@PERMANENT")

run_command("r.neighbors",
            overwrite = True,
            input = "step5@PERMANENT",
            output = "step6",
            method = "median",
            size = 5)

run_command("r.mapcalc",
            overwrite = True,
            expression = "step7=if(isnull(step6@PERMANENT )==1, step6@PERMANENT, in@PERMANENT )")

run_command("r.mapcalc",
            overwrite = True,
            expression = "step8=if(isnull(in)==0,step7,null())")
```

Comment: Also see gdal [`nearblack`](https://www.gdal.org/nearblack.html) utility (local discussion https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126227/black-edges-on-overlapped-raster-images-in-qgis/ and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/253530/removing-black-pixels-of-georeferenced-image-without-affecting-interior-pixels-u/)