# Removing black pixels of georeferenced image without affecting interior pixels using GDAL?

Tags: python, raster, gdal, fill, boundaries

I am looking for an algorithm or function in GDAL that can remove black pixels out of image boundaries. Note that I've tried **gdal_fillnodata (gdal.FillNoData)** and the result was good in most cases; But in some images I can find a lot of pixels in middle of image which are black and so they will be removed like out of boundary pixels.

What can I do for making difference between interior and exterior pixels and then removing them?

I use gdal with python.

Comment: The workflow it to digitize a polygon that presents the footprint of your image, convert it into a mask layer and then run fillnodata with -mask option http://www.gdal.org/gdal_fillnodata.html.

Comment: Do you have any idea for digitize image before building mask?

Comment: The problem is in getting a sharp mask from a fuzzy border and it may be hard to get a perfect result. Perhaps you would like to test the method that is utilizing gdal_polygonize as in this thread http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Make-gdal-polygonize-to-support-the-mask-band-td5294371.html.

Comment: [@hELLISh](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/104543/hellish), can you please provide us with the Python code that you have written so far.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/144923)

Comment: [@gisnside](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/25139/gisnside), thank you for a hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that numpy's **binary_fill_holes** function is the solution. I converted the dataset image (I) to array by **I.ReadAsArray()** function and then used **ndimage.binary_fill_holes** on the created array.
NearBlack takes some time to delete border's black pixels. So for deleting unnecessary border pixels I labeled pixels using **ndimage.measurements.label** function and then removed labels contained less that 30 percent of image pixels.

Thank you all guys for your recommendations

Comment: Could you show the code you have used so that other people with similar question can use it?

Answer (score 5):

QGIS or. GDAL NEARBLACK is what you are looking for
http://www.gdal.org/nearblack.html

Convert nearly black/white borders to black.

```
nearblack [-of format] [-white | [-color c1,c2,c3...cn]*] [-near dist] [-nb non_black_pixels]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the gdal_calc.py here is an [implementation](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_calc.py) and you can check other [examples](https://smathermather.com/2011/12/01/gdal_calc-py-raster-calculator-using-numby-functions/) to work into your problem.

I idea would be to assign a new value to a pixel needed.

Comment: Update: I used gdl_calc to create image mask and gdal_fillnodata for removing interior black pixels, but now faced another problem. Because of filling of NoData pixels with the function gdal.FillNoData(), some exterior pixels merge with interior ones and so the image's boundary enlarges while I need the real and precise mask for the image.