# Nearblack pixel makes all pixel value to 0

Tags: gdal, nearblack

I am trying to remove the dark edges around a boundary of a Drone image. I tried to use `nearblack` tool of `gdal`. However, it turns the entire pixel value to 0. This could be because all the pixel values are close to zero.

The pixel value minimum and maximum is 0.0149 and 0.0198 respectively. I want to remove or convert to no-data for 2 pixels thickness around the boarder of the data.

Below is the code I have attempted.

```
nearblack -o "stripped000-IMG_0037_4_gcp.tif" -of GTiff "wrap000-IMG_0037_4_gcp.tif"
```

Is there a way to only cut out the boundary pixels without affecting pixels inside?

Comment: The [`nearblack` doc](https://www.gdal.org/nearblack.html) states "*The processing is all done in 8bit (Bytes)*" so it won't work for your Float32 data as is.

Comment: Not an answer as I can't test (or give you detailed steps) - a slightly complicated way of achieving this *might* be to stretch your Float32 data to 0-255, run nearblack to generate a mask, then use mask to remove border Float32 data.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Yes, I used 8 bit instead of float32 but it does not work. I will try the second option and get back to you.

Comment: There's a Grass script for this at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186233/is-there-a-tool-to-shrink-grow-raster-data-edge-by-n-pixels